# Prove : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)$ is not uniformly convergent in $\left({-2,2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I've been having a hard time proving that the sequence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)$$

Does not uniformly converge for $x$ in the interval $\left({-2,2}\right)$.

I have concluded it might not be uniformly convergent due to its similarily to $x^n$ and considering a $\sin$ appears in the product, but using the Cauchy test for uniformly convergence was not helpful,

Because $\forall{N}\in\mathbb{N},\exists{m>n>N}:$
$$|\sum_{k=n}^{m}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{k}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)|$$

Then for any $x\in\left({-2,2}\right)$, we'd get $0\leq|\frac{x}{2}|<1$, and therefore cannot be assesed to find an appropriate $\varepsilon_0>0$.

How would you go about proving uniform disconvergence in this case?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For the series to converge uniformy it is necessary that $\sup_x |\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)| \to 0$.

But $\sup_x |\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)\geq |(\frac {(2-\frac 1 n)} 2 )^{n}\sin \frac {\pi (2-\frac 1 n)} 4|$  and this last quantity does not tend to $0$. In fact, it tends to $e^{-1/2}$. Hence, the series is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: Why does that prove that the series is not uniformly convergent? What's the idea behind substituting x for $(2−\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: If $\sum f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent and $S_n(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}f_n(x)$ then $|f_n(x)|=|S_n(x)-S_{n-1}(x)| \leq |S(x)-S_{n-1}(x)|+|S(x)-S_n (x)|$ where $S(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$.  Apply definition of uniform convergence to see that $f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly.  I used $2-\frac 1 n$ because uniform convergence fails near $2$. @HitoriJanai

Comment: I am sure you know that $\sum a_n$ convergent implies $a_n \to 0$. The same idea extends to uniform convergence.  @HitoriJanai

Comment: There is not better answer. Why the downvote?